# GWT Multiselect Dropdown Listbox

Tags: gwt, listbox, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I'm looking to create a multi-select dropdown listbox in GWT, but I'm not sure how to go about doing so.  I'd like it to be similar to this:

[image: Multi-select Dropdown Listbox]

Any suggestions?

Should I take gwt ListBox code and adapt it to accept objects?  Or should I forget their Listbox and try to make my own from scratch?  Or should I go in a different direction completely?  I'd really prefer not to include external libraries (like SmartGWT) if possible - I'm trying to stick with straight-up GWT.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested, I actually ended up rolling my own...

It's a TextBox with an Image next to it.  And each of these has a ClickHandler that shows/hides a DecoratedPopupPanel positioned at (TextBox.left, TextBox.top + TextBox.height).

Seems to work alright for me - and I can put anything I want in it.  Getting the Image to line up nicely with the Textbox is a little tricky in IE, but in FF it looks great.  :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm planning a UI that also has a multi-select requirement.

I currently intend using a popup dialog following the [List-Builder](http://osdpl.fluidproject.org/designPatterns/List-Builder) UI pattern, which can be easier to navigate than a multi-select drop-down list - particularly with long lists.  It's simplicity means you'll only need to use a plain list, not a drop-down/combo.