# ListBox can't be set as drop-box and multi-select?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a ListBox set to drop-down that allows multiple selections of list items.  I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439059/google-apps-script-listbox-to-dropdown-box) drop-down list and multi-select are mutually exclusive although i'm not sure from the [GWT](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ListBox.html#getVisibleItemCount%28%29) if this is the expected behavior.

Is there a workaround or alternative?  I want the user to select from lists of 20 items for query in a Fusion table.  any solution using limited real estate is sufficient.

Should this be reported in [Google Apps Scripts](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/) Issues as either a defect or enhancement?

I expected this Sample Code to be a multi-select drop-down list:

```
function doGet() {
 var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('foo');
 var main = app.createVerticalPanel().setTitle('main');
 var lb = app.createListBox(true);
 lb.setWidth("200px");
 lb.addItem("first");
 lb.addItem("second");
 lb.addItem("third");
 lb.addItem("fourth");
 lb.addItem("fifth");
 lb.addItem("sixth");
 lb.setVisibleItemCount(1);
 app.add(main);
 main.add(lb);
 return app;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, logically, it is not possible. A drop down box is designed to allow users to select a single value because when the drop down expands and you select a value, it is meant to collapse back immediately.

To conserve real estate as well have multi select, you can simply reduce the height of your multi-select list box to say, 20px.

Comment: Thank you, that will certainly work too.  I found this in GWT subsequent to my posting but your's is the practical solution for me.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570232/gwt-multiselect-dropdown-listbox

Answer (score 1):

if you follow Magento CMS->Pages, after that select any page or create a new page, there you find a store-view dropdown listox, I can't figure it till now but as it has been done for magento admin panel, I think logically it is possible to create a dropdown listbox..